# Filtering array from undefined values

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain to me why in this case:

```
const dataValues: ValueRange[] = res.data.valueRanges.filter((range: ValueRange) => range.values);

const formattedValues: Array<SheetData | undefined> = dataValues.map(this.formatSheetRanges);

const sheetData: Array<SheetData> = formattedValues.filter((sheetData: SheetData | undefined) => sheetDataGuard(sheetData));

function sheetDataGuard(data: SheetData | undefined): data is SheetData {
  return !!(<SheetData>data).user;
}
```

The sheetData array will still complain that the type of it is

```
Array<SheetData | undefined>
```

but if i change the last filtering to:

```
const sheetData: Array<SheetData> = formattedValues.filter(sheetDataGuard);
```

the typescript doesn't complain anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the typings for the method `Array<T>.filter()` in the standard TypeScript lirbary have an [overload signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1320) that specifically narrows the returned array element type if the callback function is known to be a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) function:

```
 interface Array<T> {
   filter<S extends T>(
     callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, 
     thisArg?: any
   ): S[];
 }
```

Since the type of `sheetDataGuard` is assignable to `(value: SheetData | undefined, index: number, array: Array<SheetData | undefined>) => value is SheetData`, then calling `filter` on an `Array<SheetData | undefined>` with `sheetDataGuard` as the `callbackfn` parameter will cause the compiler to select that overload with `SheetData` inferred for `S`.

But when you call it with `(sheetData: SheetData | undefined) => sheetDataGuard(sheetData)` instead, the type of that function is inferred to return just `boolean`.  That's because user-defined type guard functions [do not propagate and are not inferred for you](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10734).  A type like `x is Y` generally gets widened to `boolean` by the compiler as soon as you start doing things with it.

You could tell the compiler that your arrow function callback is also a type guard by using an arrow-function return type annotation, like this:

```
const sheetData: Array<SheetData> = formattedValues.filter(
    (sheetData: SheetData | undefined): sheetData is SheetData =>
        sheetDataGuard(sheetData)
);
```

And the compiler should be happy.  Of course if you're going to do this, you might as well forget about defining `sheetDataGuard` as a separate function:

```
const sheetData: Array<SheetData> = formattedValues.filter(
(sheetData: SheetData | undefined): sheetData is SheetData =>
    !!sheetData
);
```

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!